# Using Capybara for external applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm fairly new to testing and have been looking through all the documentation on capybara. I actually want to be able to user a driver to test the front-end. Is it possible to do tests on externally hosted sites not already a part of your rails application? I have been using CasperJS for this but wasn't sure if Capybara might have some better features or if this was possible or ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Capybara expects to be testing an in-process Rails application, but you can also use it to talk to a web server running anywhere on the internet, by setting app_host:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.mycoolsite.com'
..
visit('http://www.mycoolsite.com/page.html')
```